# Validation Rule trigger

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Hi i am trying to restrict the user to change the Acc_Id on the basis of certain field.

Below is the code : not working.

If
 yyyyyyyy__c = true

Suuuuuu__C = "Complete resolve

No one should be allow to change the AAcc_Id on the case.

```
(RecordTypeId = "vvvvvvvvvvvv"&&
((yyyyyyyy__c=true) ||
ISPICKVAL(Suuuuuu__C, "Completed"))
&& ISCHANGED( AAc_Id ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a best practice don't use `recordtypeid` in formula. because id 'll different in each environment. Name 'll be same in all environments. so your formula should be:

```
AND(
RecordType.DeveloperName = "The_recordtypename",
ISCHANGED( AAc_Id ),
OR(
    yyyyyyyy__c=true, 
    TEXT(Suuuuuu__C) = "Completed"
  )
)
```